# Java web services

Tags: java, web-services

Does anyone have good resources to learn Java web services from creation and consumption perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the [Axis introductory documents](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html). See the [Getting Started](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#BasicsGettingStarted) section and the associated sources.